# Having multiple eclipse project in one Github repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, libgdx

I want to develop a multi-platform game using libGdx (for Desktop and Android).To share my work with some friends, I created a GitHub repository.

In ecplise, I have 3 different projects :

- **MyProject-core** (most of the game)
- **MyProject-desktop** (specific desktop code)
- **MyProject-android** (specific android code)

I want to push them in my Github repository in 3 different folders.
Basicaly, I want my repository to look like this :

MyRepository

- /core/
- /desktop/
- /android/
- README.md
- LICENCE.md

My question is, Should I use 3 different local git repositories, or should I just use 1 large repo?

Comment: why not have 3 git repos?

Comment: I know it's the easiest way but all 3 projects are linked together, thus I want to share only 1 repository to my friends.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using 1 repo, do what ever is easiest for you. If you don't want 3 repos, dont make 3 repos. But if you do want to partition them maybe using [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

Comment: Whether the projects are linked or not is of little concern. Sorting this out is the task of the build tool(s).

Comment: If the code is closely related _to you_ then keep it in a single repository.

Comment: Yeah. As long as you don't need different permissions for the different projects, a single repo with projects in subdirs is fine. I do this with closely related NetBeans projects. It's convenient: you can push/pull all of them at once, view changes across all of them in a single history. And if you decide to split or merge projects, you can keep that as a continuous history in the same repo, and not have the admin overhead of creating new repos.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you may want to use [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

You can have 1 main repo, with each of the other folders being a submodule, which is just a separate repo you pull down on checkout.

When pulling down your main repo you would do `git submodule init` which pulls down the other 3 repos/submodules.

The benefit of doing this instead of just having 1 repo with these 3 folders is that each repo with different codebases is essentially its own project, with its own language and set of issues.

Comment: Thanks, I need to learn more about GIT. I'll give feedback when it's done!